# Child div overflows the parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to overflow a div over another, fitting 100% of the screen.

On my example I would like that the red bar where About Us is, to overflow the bordered div fitting 100% of the screen.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- header of the page -->
    <header id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 holder">
                    <!-- logo of the page -->
                    <a href="#" class="nav-opener visible-xs"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>                        
                    <div class="nav-holder">
                        <!-- nav of the page -->
                        <nav id="nav">
                            <ul class="list-inline">
                                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="active"><a href="quemsomos.html">About Us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="area-atuacao.html">Area</a></li>
                                <li><a href="servicos.html">Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contato.html">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- banner-block of the Page -->
    <div class="banner-block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-about">
                <div class="col-xs-12 banner-box">
                    <header class="banner-heading">
                        <h1>About Us</h1>
                    </header>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- contain main informative part of the site -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner-block {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.banner-block:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.banner-block:after {
    z-index: -1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.banner-block .bg-stretch {
    z-index: -1;
}

.banner-block.centercenter-block {
    text-align: center;
}

.banner-block.right-block {
    text-align: right;
}

.banner-box {
    height: 252px;
    padding-top: 158px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.banner-box .banner-heading {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.banner-box:before {
    content: "";
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
}

.row-about {
    background: red;
}
.banner-heading {
    margin: 11px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.banner-heading h1 {
    margin: -70px 120px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:20px;
}

#header {
    bottom: auto;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: #fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dempc3go

Comment: Sorry but your question is not really clear

Comment: I want the red div to go out of the black border.. is that clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red bar across the middle of the design you specified can be treated as an entirely separate element to the rest of the design. You can do something like this:

```
.red-tape {
  top: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 70px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  float: right;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkwAKA/)

Comment: @dante So remove the border from the wrapper and add it to the header - http://jsfiddle.net/dempc3go/3/

Comment: have a look at this.. to be clearer please.. http://gilbertogm.xyz/1.png

Answer (score 0):

as I understood your question. you are using class `.container`. which has width `width: 750px;`. So it doesnt let it grow till 100%,

```
<div class="banner-block">
        <div class="container">
             ---
        </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: hmm but how would be the fix? i took out the container div but I still can't get it right

Answer (score 0):

Also, if I understand your question correctly, to fit the entire screen, you could remove the margin and border from #wrapper, which would make your "about us" section fit the entire screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/dempc3go/2/

CSS:

```
    .banner-block {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.banner-block:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.banner-block:after {
    z-index: -1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.banner-block .bg-stretch {
    z-index: -1;
}

.banner-block.centercenter-block {
    text-align: center;
}

.banner-block.right-block {
    text-align: right;
}

.banner-box {
    height: 252px;
    padding-top: 158px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.banner-box .banner-heading {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.banner-box:before {
    content: "";
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
}

.row-about {
    background: red;
}
.banner-heading {
    margin: 11px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.banner-heading h1 {
    margin: -70px 120px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
    bottom: auto;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: #fff;
}
```